# Error TC2322 when executing the Angular4 application build

Tags: angular

An error occurs when executing the "ng build" command:

```
ERROR in src/app/model/rest.datasource.ts(34,5): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Product | Order | Product[] | Order[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Product[]>'.
  Type 'Product | Order | Product[] | Order[]' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.
```

File rest.datasource.ts:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Request, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Product } from './product.model';
import { Cart } from './cart.model';
import { Order } from './order.model';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

const PROTOCOL = 'http';
const PORT = 3500;

@Injectable()
export class RestDataSource {
  baseUrl: string;
  auth_token: string;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.baseUrl = `${PROTOCOL}://${location.hostname}:${PORT}/`;
  }

  authenticate(user: string, pass: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.request(new Request({
      method: RequestMethod.Post,
      url: this.baseUrl + 'login',
      body: {name: user, password: pass}
    })).map(response => {
      let r = response.json();
      this.auth_token = r.success ? r.token : null;
      return r.success;
    });
  }

  getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Get, 'products');
  }

  saveProduct(product: Product): Observable<Product> {
    return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Post, 'products', product, true);
  }

  updateProduct(product): Observable<Product> {
    return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Put, `products/${product.id}`, product, true);
  }

  deleteProduct(id: number): Observable<Product> {
    return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Delete, `products/${id}`, null, true);
  }

  getOrders(): Observable<Order[]> {
    return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Get, 'orders', null, true);
  }

  deleteOrder(id: number): Observable<Order> {
    return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Delete, `orders/${id}`, null, true);
  }

  updateOrder(order: Order): Observable<Order> {
    return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Put, `orders/${order.id}`, order, true);
  }
  saveOrder(order: Order): Observable<Order> {
    return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Post, 'orders', order);
  }

  private sendRequest(verb: RequestMethod, url: string, body?: Product | Order, auth: boolean = false)
    : Observable<Product | Product[] | Order | Order[]> {

    let request = new Request({
      method: verb,
      url: this.baseUrl + url,
      body: body
    });
    if (auth && this.auth_token != null) {
      request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer<${this.auth_token}>`);
    }
    return this.http.request(request).map(response => response.json());
  }
}
```

Error in Terminal:
[Error TS2322](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXpRa.png)

Help me to understand, it is a mistake in the code or a compiler error?

PS: This error occurred when the "ng serve" command was executed, but after saving the changes in the rest.datasource.ts file, the webpack compiled and ran the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `sendRequest` returns several types :

```
Observable<Product | Product[] | Order | Order[]>
```

And in your component you probably declared a variable that will hold the result like so :

```
myvar: Product[];
```

But what you should have really done is

```
myvar: Product | Product[] | Order | Order[];
```

Your error comes from the fact that your variable can have several types of data, but you only cover one.

Comment: Thanks!
But I removed from the function sendRequest () ":Observable <Product | Product [] | Order | Order []>", so that do not assign multiple types of one variable and the error is gone!

Is it possible to allow such a correction?

Comment: Hum sorry what ? From what you've told, it seems you already made your correction :)